# #HTACCESS hide multi PHP GET tag from the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, replace, get, tags

i'm replacing this

```
localhost/load.php?code=foo
```

with this

```
localhost/foo
```

using this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

works pretty good! but what about including other get tag in the same URL like

```
localhost/load.php?user=foo&code=foo
```

replaced it with htaccess to be like

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?user=$1&code=$1
```

but doesn't work as well! so what is the correct htaccess code to do this?

Comment: You're right, but this one worked `^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$` adding the question mark before the dollar sign, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your other RewriteRules you might want to use a catch-all rule with the `QSA` (QueryStringAppend) flag.

The QueryString is the part after `?` so `user=foo&code=foo`.

If you have a rule that says:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ load.php?__path=$1 [QSA]
```

And you call:

```
my.domain.com/page/sub?foo=bar&baz=ipsum
```

`load.php` will get the following GET:

```
__path = page/sub
foo = bar
baz = ipsum
```

With a rule like this you can handle *any* URL.